# How to write simple script in vim?

Tags: vim

Here I got simple task for skilled vimmers. I need to reformat my css file. There are commands to do this:

```
%s/}/&\r/g
%s/  /   /g
retab!
echo "You done did it!"
```

But I don't want to type these commands every time I need to format my css file (I get it after convert less file by WinLess program). Now I put these commands into cssformat.vim file, and put this file into vim runtime folder. In my vimrc I set:

autocmd Filetype css nmap   :so $VIM/vim73/cssformat.vim

It's works, of course. But I wonder how can I do this task better? In the begginig I want to put these commands in my vimrc (to create a simple function), but I don't know how to do this correctly.

p.s. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the commands from your script into a function:

```
function! ReformatCss()
    " Place your commands here.
endfunction
```

And move the stuff into your `.vimrc`. Now you can invoke this via `:call ReformatCss()`.

To top it off and make it even simpler, define your own command:

```
command! ReformatCss call ReformatCss()
```

Now you can invoke via `:ReformatCss`. Voila!

---

You can learn more at `:help usr_40.txt` and `:help :command`. For example, if you only need this for CSS files, you can turn this into a buffer-local command through `command -buffer` and moving the function and command definition to `~/.vim/ftplugin/css_reformat.vim`

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, Ingo Karkat!